# using MySql data in function/method

Tags: c#, mysql

What is the correct way to do this?

```
MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
while (reader.Read())
{
    //Console.WriteLine(reader["name"].ToString());
    SendFax(reader["title"].ToString(),
            reader["filepath"].ToString(),
            reader["name"].ToString(),
            reader["name"].ToString());
}
```

Also, how do you check to see if it returns any rows in an if statement?

Like:

```
if($numrows>"0")
{ 
    //execute code
}
else
{
    //do nothing
}
```

Full Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using FAXCOMLib;

namespace MysqlConnection1
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string connString = "Server=localhost;Port=3306;Database=test;Uid=myuser;password=mypassword;";
        MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connString);
        MySqlCommand command = conn.CreateCommand();
        command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM firstcsharp";
        //command.CommandText = "UPDATE blah blah";
        //conn.Open();
        //conn.ExecuteNonQuery();
        //conn.Close();

        try
        {

            conn.Open();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        if(reader.HasRows){

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            //Console.WriteLine(reader["name"].ToString());
            SendFax(reader["title"].ToString(),reader["filepath"].ToString(),reader["name"].ToString(),reader["name"].ToString());
        }

        }
        //Console.ReadLine();

        public void SendFax(string DocumentName, string FileName, string RecipientName, string FaxNumber) 
    { 
        if (FaxNumber != "") 
        { 
            try
            {
                FAXCOMLib.FaxServer faxServer = new FAXCOMLib.FaxServerClass(); 
                faxServer.Connect(Environment.MachineName); 

                
                FAXCOMLib.FaxDoc faxDoc = (FAXCOMLib.FaxDoc)faxServer.CreateDocument(FileName);  
            
                faxDoc.RecipientName = RecipientName;
                faxDoc.FaxNumber = FaxNumber; 

                faxDoc.DisplayName = DocumentName;
                

                int Response = faxDoc.Send(); 
                

                faxServer.Disconnect();

            }
            catch(Exception Ex){MessageBox.Show(Ex.Message);}
        } 
       

    
    }


}
}
```

**Errors:**

> Error  1   } expected  c:\documents and settings\bruser\my documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\FirstMysqlConnection\MysqlConnection1\Program.cs  41  14  MysqlConnection1
>
> Error  2   An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'MysqlConnection1.Program.SendFax(string, string, string, string)'    c:\documents and settings\bruser\my documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\FirstMysqlConnection\MysqlConnection1\Program.cs  38  17  MysqlConnection1
>
> Error  3   Interop type 'FAXCOMLib.FaxServerClass' cannot be embedded. Use the applicable interface instead.   c:\documents and settings\bruser\my documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\FirstMysqlConnection\MysqlConnection1\Program.cs  50  52  MysqlConnection1
>
> Error  4   The name 'MessageBox' does not exist in the current context c:\documents and settings\bruser\my documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\FirstMysqlConnection\MysqlConnection1\Program.cs  68  25  MysqlConnection1

Comment: What's wrong with what you have now?  Looks fine to me.  Does it not work correctly?  Are you looking for easier-to-read code?

Comment: I am getting an object reference is required error.  I was also getting some kind of unicode error when ToString() was at the end of SendFax("");

Comment: @user1046434 for first error you are missing  "}" , would you pls check it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:** Regarding your error messages:

1. This error indicates your braces are mismatched.  I believe you are missing one at the  end of `Main` method (add another `}` at the end).  One way to help with this is to keep matching braces on the same vertical line so they are easy to see - tab them over to match.  Also, you can use Edit -> Advanced -> Format Document feature in Visual Studio to help see the mismatch.
2. You are trying to call `SendFax`, which is non-static, from `Main`, which is static. This is easily fixed by adding `static` to make it `public *static* void SendFax`.
3. Might have to go to documentation/support on this 3rd-party library to figure out how you are supposed to reference it correctly.
4. To use the [`MessageBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/411ze57x.aspx) class you need to add a reference to `System.Windows.Forms.dll` library and also to the namespace `System.Windows.Forms` at the top.

---

The code you have now looks like it should work.  One thing to note is that if `SendFax` is a long running operation, you will probably want to either run it asynchronously, or download all the data from the database at once and process it afterward so that the connection can be closed.  Connections to databases should be opened for as short as possible.

```
MySqlDataAdapter adap = new MySqlDataAdapter(commandText, connectionString);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
adap.Fill(dt);

foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows) {
    string title = dr["title"] as string;
    string filepath = dr["filepath"] as string;
    string name = dr["name"] as string;

    SendFax(title, filepath, name, name);
}
```

Regarding your second question, using the above method it's as simple as checking

```
if (dt.Rows.Count > 0) ...
```

Otherwise, you can do something like this:

```
if (reader.Read()) {
    // there is data - now use do...while instead of while
    // because first row was consumed by if statement
    do {
        // process data
    } while (reader.Read());
}
```

Comment: Ok I see what you are saying.

Comment: You are wrong in the 4th point, @user1046434 should reference `System.Windows.Forms.dll` and not `System.web.forms.dll`, and add the following using directive `System.Windows.Forms;` instead of `System.Web.Forms;` (It's even referenced in the link you added). You should edit your answer.

Comment: @Nacereddine: Yoiks.. my mind read one thing and wrote another! Thanks for the catch :)

Answer (score 2):

I didn't understand what you're looking for in the 1st part of your question (as it looks fine), as for the second part you can use :

```
if(reader.HasRows){
    //code here
}
```

#### Edit :

**Error 1:** You must add a closing curly (`}`) brace to the main function before declaring the `SendFax()` function

**Error 2:** May have been cause by the first one. (since this function `SendFax()` was declared inside another function `main()`).

**Error 3:** Solution is available [here](https://blogs.msdn.com/themes/blogs/generic/post.aspx?WeblogApp=mshneer&y=2009&m=12&d=07&WeblogPostName=interop-type-xxx-cannot-be-embedded-use-the-applicable-interface-instead&GroupKeys=)

**Error 4:** Add this using directive `using System.Windows.Forms;`

The code should now looks someting like this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using FAXCOMLib;

namespace MysqlConnection1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string connString = "Server=localhost;Port=3306;Database=test;Uid=myuser;password=mypassword;";
            MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connString);
            MySqlCommand command = conn.CreateCommand();
            command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM firstcsharp";

            try
            {
                conn.Open();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }

            MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

            if(reader.HasRows){
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    SendFax(reader["title"].ToString(),
                            reader["filepath"].ToString(),
                            reader["name"].ToString(),
                            reader["name"].ToString());
                }
                reader.Close();
            }
        }       
        public void SendFax(string DocumentName, string FileName, string RecipientName, string FaxNumber) 
        { 
            if (FaxNumber != "") 
            { 
                try
                {
                    FAXCOMLib.FaxServer faxServer = new FAXCOMLib.FaxServerClass(); 
                    faxServer.Connect(Environment.MachineName); 

                    FAXCOMLib.FaxDoc faxDoc = (FAXCOMLib.FaxDoc)faxServer.CreateDocument(FileName);  

                    faxDoc.RecipientName = RecipientName;
                    faxDoc.FaxNumber = FaxNumber; 

                    faxDoc.DisplayName = DocumentName;

                    int Response = faxDoc.Send(); 

                    faxServer.Disconnect();

                }
                catch(Exception ex){ 
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); 
                }
            } 
        }
    }
}
```